# Powershell: conditional flag based on a local variable

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, flags, powershell-5.0

There is a variable in my PowerShell script called `$IncludeSubfolders` (either `0` or `1`)

Depending on its value, I would like to call `Get-ChildItem` method either with or without the `-Recurse` option.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
if($IncludeSubfolders) {
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Name $FileMask -Recurse
} else {
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Name $FileMask
}
```

I would like to avoid this branching and just have a single line of code calling `Get-ChildItem` with `-Recurse` flag if `$IncludeSubfolders` is `1` or without it if it is `0`.

Is this achievable? How?

Powershell version 5.0.10586.117

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the more descriptive values of `$true` and `$false` for `$IncludeSubfolders`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$IncludeSubfolders` should ideally be a boolean value, not an integer, but it can be converted easily.

Even if you must keep it an integer, the code is the same.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Name $FileMask -Recurse:$IncludeSubfolders
```

### Why?

Because `-Recurse` is a Switch parameter, which is a special type of boolean in which an explicit value is not needed. Present makes it true, absent makes it false. But all switch parameters can take an explicit value as well, using the colon directly after it.

If you try to use a non-boolean value in an expression where a boolean is expected, PowerShell will do its best to coalesce that value to boolean, and in this case `0` will become `$false` while `1` will become `$true`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on $IncludeSubfolders data type. It originates from an SQL Server table (bit data type). I can easily make it boolean but if it works as is, I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Does it work for an external executable being called with a call operator `&`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Name $FileMask -Recurse:$IncludeSubfolders
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That is why I up voted the answer by @briantist. I've been here for a while. When I have time for explanations I type them. When I don't, I give the OP something to get them going until I can come back to type more.